# Call AsyncTask from button click and start another activity populated with listview after doInBackground has completed

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to use an Asynctask to load data from a jdbc driver and place this data in a multimap which then gets loaded into a listview

I currently have mainactivity.java with a button and clicklistener (this button on mainactivity is used to start the next activity).

The secondactivity already has a button initiated and also has a listview that is populated with the data from backgroundpickingtask.java. secondactivity.java is actually where I call "new BackgrounPickingTask.execute();

The problem i have is the button already in secondactivity.java is showing up first, but the listview takes a second or two before it shows up in secondactivity.java.

I think it would be best to have the data ready from mainactivity so the secondactivity button (R.id.nextButton) doesn't always beat out the listview when starting the secondactivity. Sorry if I am unclear but I tried to explain it the best I could. Would truly appreciate any help or suggestions. I am kinda new to android app development. Below are the classes.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button pickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickButton);

    View.OnClickListener pickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    pickButton.setOnClickListener(pickListener);

}
```

**BackGroundPickingTask.java**

```
public class BackgroundPickingTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


private Connection conn;
private String HOST = "jdbc:postgresql://IPaddress:(port number)/";
private String DataBaseNAME = "database";
private String USERNAME = "the_username";
private String PASSWORD = "the_password";
private PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private long rowCounter = 0;
Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

private String sql =
        "SELECT id, name, title, project from thattable"

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) (SecondActivity.list.getAdapter());
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                HOST + DataBaseNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        //Prepares statement to execute query
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        //Execute prepared statement
        rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
        //add results from sql query to multimap
        while (rs.next()) {
            myMultimap.put(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2) + " (" + rs.getString(3) + " - " + rs.getString(4) + ")");
            ++rowCounter;
        }
        if (rowCounter == 0) {
            //System.out.println("There are no results");
        }
        rs.close();
        pStmt.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //for loop to add values from each key to adapter
    for (String keyz : myMultimap.keySet()) {
        publishProgress(keyz);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    //formatting my string here to organize in listview
    String formattedString = "\nName (title- project):\n " + myMultimap.get(values[0]).toString()
            .replace("," , "\n").trim()
            .replace("[","").trim()
            .replace("]","").trim();
    //adding results to listview adapter
    adapter.add("ID: "  + values[0] + formattedString);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String values) {
}
```

**SecondActivity.class**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
public static ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Button createWave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new
            ArrayList<String>()));

    new BackgroundPickingTask().execute();            

}
```

Comment: Setup a callback from the AsyncTask that you can listen for in your activity and trigger the next activity from there. Or use a loading bar and handle setting things up in onPostExecute().

Comment: By the way, Android was not really meant to perform JDBC connections. Forming REST APIs and doing HTTP calls is the correct approach

Comment: I'm able to make the jdbc connection just fine though. Why would http calls be the correct approach? I was iffy when choosing between jdbc and api's to begin with. I'd like to be able to create, modify, and receive data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Interface with a method with a ArrayAdapter as parameter..

Implement it on SecondActivity..

Call the Interface method you created in the onPostExecute of BackGroundPickingTask with the arrayAdapter as a parameter..

Populate the listView in the implemented method on SecondActivity..

And that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface TaskInterface{
   void onLoadingCompleted();
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**
make your view `visibility` to `invisible` in you `xml` by default.
replace AysncTask call with

```
new BackgroundPickingTask(new TaskInterface(){
    @Override
    public void onLoadingCompleted(){
        yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
 }
)).execute();
```

In your AsyncTask add paramtered constructor

```
public class BackgroundPickingTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private TaskInterface taskInterface;
public BackgroundPickingTask(TaskInterface task) {
        super();
        taskInterface = task 
    }
```

Comment: Placing visibility to invisible by default kept it invisible. Is there a way it can be loaded into the listview by the time i click the button to get to secondactivity? That way it is populated and is quicker when going to the next activity